# Is there a "to or from" email rule in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter, rules

It's annoying to have to create a rule to move all messages from certain people to a certain folder, and then create another to move all messages to those same people to that same folder. Has anyone been able to find a work-around yet?

Answer (score 0):

No workarounds here. You can't combine inbound and outbount rules, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not native rule for such requirement in Outlook client. Outlook rule is also known as inbox rule. It generally auto-proceeds the incoming messages other than outgoing messages.